# Запуск Queryset для теста Django из питоновского файла

Tags: python, django

```
from table.models import Author

entry_list = list(Author.object.all())
print entry_list
```

Создал питоновский файл в директории с settings.py для теста Джанги, **ошибка**:

> **django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
> Requested setting
> DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings
> are not configured. You must either
> define the environment variable
> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure()...**

Пробовал импорт import os
`os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'`  из советов по решению таких проблем, такой способ не помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ выполнить произвольный код в джанговском окружении - использовать [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/). Но конкретно для тестов я бы рекомендовал [тесты](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/) и использовать.